What are the possible cardinalities of a given universal-algebra variety?
Here's what I know so far.

For semigroups, the left zero semigroup on a set shows that any cardinality works. I think a very similar argument works for any variety whose equations all have an operation on both sides at the top level: make all the operations return the same element.

For commutative rings, any finite $n \ge 1$ gives us an example $\Bbb{Z}/n$; and for any infinite $\kappa$, a free commutative ring on a set of size $\kappa$ also has size $\kappa$. So any $\kappa > 0$ works. We can't get size $0$ because the ring needs a $0$ and a $1$, but it's possible that $0 = 1$, so size $1$ is fine. This also gives the answer for general rings, abelian groups, groups, and monoids.

Since the variety is closed under small products, the class of that variety's cardinalities is too.

For vector spaces over some fixed field $k$, the space is the direct sum over some basis of size $\tau$, so its cardinality $\kappa$ is $|k|^\tau$ (when $\tau$ is finite) or $|k| \tau$ (when $\tau$ is infinite). For example if the size of $k$ is a prime $p$, then the answer seems to be that $\kappa$ is $p^i$ (for $i = 0, 1, 2 \ldots$), or any infinite cardinal.

Even if $R$ is only a ring with left inverses of nonzero elements, a module over $R$ which has more than one element must be at least as large as $R$: for a nonzero $x$, $r_0 x = r_1 x$ means that $r_0 = r_1$.


All this suggests that the answer depends heavily on the variety and in particular on its constants. Given a variety, is there an easy way to describe its cardinalities? Maybe an efficient algorithm?
Bonus question: given a class $C$ of cardinalities, which is closed under arbitrary products, can we decide whether there is a variety whose possible cardinalities are precisely $C$? For $C = \{0\}$, the answer seems to be no: any variety can be realized by a singleton, by specifying that all operations return the unique element. But $C = \{1\}$ does have a variety: the variety with one constant $t$ and one equation $x = t$ can be realized only by a singleton. What if $C$ is, say, $\{0, 1\}$? Or $\{\kappa: \kappa \ge 11\}$?

Your calculation for vector spaces is not correct. Recall that a basis yields a direct sum.

Concerning your last paragraph, notice that if a variety is not trivial (i.e., there is some algebra $A$ in that variety such that $|A|>1$), then that variety has infinite algebras (from direct powers of the non-trivial algebra), so its set of cardinalities can't be only a finite set (and it can't include $0$, as far as I know, but I suppose that depends on conventions, which may be different for others). Then apply Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem, and the variety has algebras of all infinite cardinals.

Thanks @MartinBrandenburg, I think I fixed it.

@SassatelliGiulio, nice.

@amrsa: Lowenheim-Skolem is guaranteed to give ALL infinite cardinals only when the language of $\mathcal{V}$ is countable.

@KeithKearnes Yes, I took that for granted, my bad. Indeed, a very common case doesn't have a countable language: a vector space over an uncountable field, such as $\mathbb R$.

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a variety of algebras.
Define the support of $\mathcal{V}$
(= $\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$)
to be the class of cardinals that are realizable
as cardinalities of members of $\mathcal{V}$.

Claim. A class $\mathcal{C}$ of cardinals
is the support of a variety if and only if

 $1\in \mathcal{C}$,

 if $m,n\in \mathcal{C}$ are finite, then $m\cdot n\in \mathcal{C}$, and

 if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal greater than $1$
that belongs to $\mathcal{C}$,
then every infinite cardinal
$\lambda\geq \kappa$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}$.


I will refer to these by number below as 'Items 1, 2, and 3'.

These conditions do not refer to $0$. Some might disallow empty algebras,
but for this answer I will allow them and hence will allow
the possibility that $0\in\mathcal{C}=\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$.
We will have $0\in\mathcal{C}=\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$
iff $\mathcal{V}$ has no $0$-ary operations.
It is not hard to see that if
$\mathcal{C}=\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$, then
$\mathcal{C}\cup \{0\}$ is the support of the variety obtained
from $\mathcal{V}$ by replacing each $0$-ary operation
of $\mathcal{V}$ with a constant unary operation naming the same element.
It is also not hard to see that if
$\mathcal{C}=\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$, then
$\mathcal{C} - \{0\}$ is the support of the variety obtained
from $\mathcal{V}$ by adding a single $0$-ary operation,
subject to no constraints, to the
language of $\mathcal{V}$. (This will change the number of models
of a given size, but it will not change size.)
Thus, $\mathcal{C}$ is a support
iff $\mathcal{C}\cup \{0\}$ is a support iff
$\mathcal{C}- \{0\}$ is a support.
Item 1 in the list above
asserts that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a support, then
$1\in \mathcal{C}$. Thus $1$ belongs to any support and $0$
may be freely added to or subtracted from any support to obtain
a support. Let me therefore focus henceforth on the class
$\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})-\{0,1\}$ of 'nontrivial'
cardinals in the support, which I will call
the 'nontrivial support' and when I use the symbol
$\mathcal{C}$ for $\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$
I will use the symbol
$\mathcal{C}_0$ for
$\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})-\{0,1\}$, the
nontrivial support of $\mathcal{V}$.
I intend to explain why Items 2 and 3 above
characterize 'nontrivial supports'.
The Items above say that there are two kinds
of nontrivial supports.
The first type is an upper interval of infinite cardinals
$[\kappa,\infty) = \{\lambda\;|\;\lambda\geq \kappa\}$
where $\kappa$ is an arbitrary infinite cardinal.
The second type consists of a multiplicatively
closed set of finite cardinals $>1$ together with
all infinite cardinals.
Let me explain why these are the types of nontrivial supports.
Necessity of Items 2 and 3 for nontrivial supports:
Assume that $\mathcal{C}_0=\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})-\{0,1\}$
is the nontrivial support of some variety $\mathcal{V}$.
The fact that $\mathcal{C}_0$ must satisfy Item 2 has already
been noted in the statement of the question.
For Item 3,
assume that $\kappa$ is the least cardinal greater than $1$
that belongs to $\mathcal{C}_0$. Choose $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{V}$
of cardinality $\kappa$. Choose any infinite
$\lambda\geq \kappa$ and then choose any Boolean algebra
$\mathbf{B}$ of cardinality $\lambda$. The Boolean power
$\mathbf{A}[\mathbf{B}]^*$ belongs to $\mathcal{V}$
and has cardinality $|\mathbf{A}[\mathbf{B}]^*|=\kappa\cdot\lambda=
\lambda$, so $\lambda\in\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})=\mathcal{C}_0$.
(Note: $\mathbf{A}[\mathbf{B}]^*$ is the algebra of continuous
functions from the Stone space $\mathbf{B}^*$ of $\mathbf{B}$
to the discretely topologized algebra $\mathbf{A}$.)

Sufficiency of Items 2 and 3 for nontrivial supports:
Let $\mathcal{C}_0$ be any class of cardinals satisfying
Items 2 and 3. We need to construct a variety whose nontrivial support is $\mathcal{C}_0$.
Case 1. $\mathcal{C}_0$ is an upper interval of
of infinite cardinals.
In this case, $\mathcal{C}_0$
consists of all cardinals greater or equal
to some infinite cardinal $\kappa$ according
to Item 3.
We construct a variety whose nontrivial support
is like this. Choose a set $A$ of cardinality $\kappa$,
equip it with all finitary operations
$f\colon A^n\to A$ to obtain an algebra
$\mathbf{A}$, and let $\mathcal{V}=\textsf{HSP}(\mathbf{A})$.
By the Necessity part of the argument, the nontrivial
part of the support of this variety contains
all cardinals $\lambda\geq |\mathbf{A}|\;(=\kappa)$.
We need to show that the nontrivial
part of the support of this variety contains no other cardinal,
i.e. $\mathcal{V}$ contains no algebra $\mathbf{B}$
such that $1<|\mathbf{B}|<|\mathbf{A}|$. In fact, we will see
that if $\mathbf{B}\in \mathcal{V}$ has more than one element,
then there is an embedding of $\mathbf{A}$ into $\mathbf{B}$,
so $1<|\mathbf{B}|<|\mathbf{A}|$ is impossible.
For each $a\in A$, the definition of $\mathbf{A}$
guarantees that there is a
constant unary operation $c_a\colon A\to A$
satisfying $(\forall x\in A)(c_a(x)=a)$. For each basic
operation $f\colon A^n\to A$ of $\mathbf{A}$,
if $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=a$ in $\mathbf{A}$, then the identity
$f(c_{a_1}(x),\ldots,c_{a_n}(x))=c_a(x)$
belongs to the equational theory of $\mathbf{A}$.
This implies that every algebra $\mathbf{B}\in \mathcal{V}$
satisfies
$f^{\mathbf{B}}(c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(x),\ldots,c_{a_n}^{\mathbf{B}}(x))=c_a^{\mathbf{B}}(x)$.
This suffices to imply that if $\mathbf{B}\in \mathcal{V}$
is nonempty and $b\in B$, then
the function $\varphi\colon a\mapsto c_a^{\mathbf{B}}(b)$
is a homomorphism from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$.
I will refer to this as the 'canonical homomorphism'
from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$. I will argue that if
$|\mathbf{B}|>1$, then the canonical homomorphism
is an embedding, so $1<|\mathbf{B}|<|\mathbf{A}|$ is impossible.
It is not hard to see that $\mathbf{A}$ is simple,
so the canonical homomorphism is 1-1 or constant.
I argue that if the canonical homomorphism
$\varphi\colon \mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ is
constant, then $|\mathbf{B}|=1$.
$\mathbf{A}$ has an operation $d\colon A^3\to A$
defined by $d(x,y,z) = z$ if $x=y$ and
$d(x,y,z)=x$ if $x\neq y$. The identity
(i) $d(x,x,z)=z$
belongs to the equational theory
of $\mathbf{A}$, so it will be satisfied by any
$\mathbf{B}\in \mathcal{V}$.
For $a_1\neq a_2$ in $\mathbf{A}$, the identity
(ii)
$d(c_{a_1}(x),c_{a_2}(x),z)=c_{a_1}(x)$
belongs to the equational theory
of $\mathbf{A}$, so it will be satisfied by any
$\mathbf{B}\in \mathcal{V}$. If the canonical homomorphism
$\varphi\colon \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{B}$ is not 1-1,
then there exist $a_1\neq a_2$ in $\mathbf{A}$
such that $c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(b)=\varphi(a_1)=\varphi(a_2)=c_{a_2}^{\mathbf{B}}(b)$
holds. Thus
$z\stackrel{(i)}{=}d^{\mathbf{B}}(c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(b),c_{a_2}^{\mathbf{B}}(b),z)\stackrel{(ii)}{=}c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(b)$ holds.
This asserts that if the canonical homomorphism
$\varphi\colon \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{B}$ is not 1-1,
then $\mathbf{B}$ satisfies
$(\forall z)(z=c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(b))$, which asserts that any element of $\mathbf{B}$
equals $c_{a_1}^{\mathbf{B}}(b)$.
This forces $|\mathbf{B}|=1$, as desired.
This completes the proof that $\mathcal{V}$
is a variety whose nontrivial support consists
exactly of all $\lambda\geq \kappa$.
Case 2. $\mathcal{C}_0$ contains a finite cardinal $k>1$.
We may assume that $k$ has been chosen so that it
is the least cardinal $>1$ in $\mathcal{C}_0$.
Then Item 3 guarantees that $\mathcal{C}_0$ contains
every infinite cardinal, while Item 2 guarantees
that the set of finite cardinals in $\mathcal{C}_0$
is a multiplicatively closed set.
We need to show that such a class $\mathcal{C}_0$
is the nontrivial support of some variety. It suffices
to produce a variety $\mathcal{V}$ whose
nontrivial support agrees with $\mathcal{C}_0$
on the finite cardinals, since for any such
$\mathcal{V}$ we will have that
$\textrm{Supp}(\mathcal{V})$ contains all infinite
cardinals by the fact that Item 3 is a necessary condition
on supports.
Let $1<k_1<k_2<\cdots$ be a sequence of finite cardinals $>1$.
Let $A_i$ be a set of size $k_i$.
For any sequence $\Gamma = (f_1, f_2, \ldots)$, where $f_i$ is
an operation on $A_i$ and all $f_i$ in the sequence $\Gamma$
have the same arity, define an operation
symbol $f_{\Gamma}$. The set $\Omega$
of all such $f_{\Gamma}$ will be our operator domain.
Define algebras $\mathbf{A}_i=(A_i,\Omega)$
by stipulating that $f_{\Gamma}^{\mathbf{A}_i} = f_i$.
Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the variety generated by
the set of all $\mathbf{A}_i$. It is proved in
Theorem 10.3 of my 1988 UC Berkeley PhD thesis
that the only finite members of $\mathcal{V}$
are the finite products of the $\mathbf{A}_i$'s.
Thus, the finite part of the nontrivial support of $\mathcal{V}$
is the multiplicative closure of $K=\{k_1,k_2,\ldots\}$.
If this set was already multiplicatively closed, then $K$ is exactly
the finite part of the nontrivial support of $\mathcal{V}$.
This shows how to realize any multiplicatively closed
of finite cardinals as the finite part of the nontrivial
support of a variety. This completes the argument that Items 1, 2, and 3
are sufficient to characterize supports of varieties.
